# How to install a LED light over an old square recessed box?

Tags: electrical, lighting, recessed-lighting

My question is similar to an old question posted by someone else 3 yrs ago but hasn't been active for 2 yrs (see link). My house was built in the 1963, so I have two old 9 sq inch ceiling lights with a recessed box measuring 8 sq in, inside is a 6 sq in housing. I would like to install an LED surface mount light over it using a light bulb socket pigtail (see links to options considering), but I can't find a mounting plate or crossbar large enough to cover the hole.

[Old Question posted by Chester](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/69479/how-to-hang-modern-fixture-over-old-square-recessed-box)

[Commercial Electric LED Flat panel option](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-1-ft-x-1-ft-White-LED-Edge-Lit-Flat-Panel-Flushmount-74029-HD/206040712)

[Altair LED Flushmount option](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GWEZGGU)

[image: old recessed box image]

Answer (score 1):

I have installed a couple of those flat panel LED’s. I would go with that one.

The one I installed had some slots in the panel for screws, you would mark those locations on the ceiling and then drill and install anchors so that you could screw the panel to the ceiling into those anchors.

This one does appear to have a mounting plate  that attaches to the box but because the plate  is so big you could just  drill holes in the plate  that would line up with the ceiling joist  but it’s not a heavy light  so some good quality anchors would be sufficient if you can’t lineup with a joist .